# Swapping Two Structs in C (Dynamic Memory Allocation)

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to swap two structs in C. The issue is I have to use `malloc()` in order to allocate memory for **n** number of structs during run-time. The structs have to accessed using the base pointer of the memory allocated by `malloc()`. I also tried typecasting `(triangle*)malloc()` But that didn't work either. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
typedef struct triangle triangle;

void swapStructs(triangle *a, triangle *b)
{
    triangle temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void print_structs(triangle *tr, int n)
{
    printf("VALUES BEFORE SWAPPING...\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr->a);
        printf("B[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr->b);
        printf("C[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr->c);
        tr++;
    }
    swapStructs(&tr[0], &tr[1]);

    printf("VALUES AFTER SWAPPING...\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr->a);
        printf("B[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr->b);
        printf("C[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr->c);
        tr++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    swapStructs(&tr[0], &tr[1]);

    print_structs(tr, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Rather than printing the correct output, it printed garbage values.

Comment: How do you know if your `scanf()` function actually read any data?  You're not checking any return values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It does read data, I tried printing the values of the structs in the `print_structs()` function

Comment: @DevashishLahariya: Please explain how it didn't work. Did the code fail to compile? When you printed the structs, were they not swapped? Did it print something else entirely? Did it print nothing? Did it catch your computer on fire?

Comment: @DevashishLahariya: If you don't think your problem has anything to do with the user input portion, why not remove that from the sample code and just hard-code the numbers? `int n = 3; triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle)); tr[0].a = 1; tr[0].b=2; tr[0].c=3; tr[1].a = 4; ...`

Comment: @BillLynch It printed Garbage Values even for the struct I didn't try swapping. And No, no fires until now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `tr++;` instructions.

Also the `print_structs` should be fixed as follow:

```
void print_structs(triangle *tr, int n)
{
    printf("VALUES BEFORE SWAPPING...\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr[i].a);
        printf("B[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr[i].b);
        printf("C[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr[i].c);
    }
    swapStructs(&tr[0], &tr[1]);

    printf("VALUES AFTER SWAPPING...\n");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("A[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr[i].a);
        printf("B[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr[i].b);
        printf("C[%d]: %d\n", i ,tr[i].c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, and replace `tr->a` with `tr[i].a`